# Creating a total difference comparison row automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is some sample data showing various Statues with a Start Date and End Date for a particular ID.

[image]

The Days Elapsed column is a datediff for the particular row.

```
select 
    *,
    DateDiff(d,StartDate,EndDate) as DaysElapsed 
from 
    #Sample
```

What I'm trying to do is compare the Total Days Elapsed for a particular ID against the first StartDate, and the greatest End Date.

In the case of ID 1, there were 22 days elapsed (7+8+7), but when you compare the first Start Date (2019-11-01) with the last End Date (2019-11-25), it is actually 24. So I need to add another row for ID 1 with a Status of "Incorrect Flow" with a Days Elapsed value of 2. If it matches, then no row would be added.

Where a record has an End Date value of NULL, it should simply ignore that ID all together. So the expected result would be:

[image]

Sample Data

```
Create Table #Sample
(
    ID int,
    Status varchar(20),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
)

insert into #Sample
(
    ID,
    Status,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
)
select
    1,
    'Status 1',
    '01 Nov 2019',
    '08 Nov 2019'
union all
select
    1,
    'Status 2',
    '10 Nov 2019',
    '18 Nov 2019'
union all
select
    1,
    'Status 3',
    '18 Nov 2019',
    '25 Nov 2019'
union all
select
    2,
    'Status 1',
    '02 Nov 2019',
    '09 Nov 2019'
union all
select
    2,
    'Status 2',
    '16 Nov 2019',
    '29 Nov 2019'
union all
select
    2,
    'Status 3',
    '29 Nov 2019',
    '03 Dec 2019'
union all
select
    2,
    'Status 4',
    '03 Dec 2019',
    '08 Dec 2019'
union all
select
    3,
    'Status 1',
    '01 Dec 2019',
    '03 Dec 2019'
union all
select
    3,
    'Status 2',
    '03 Dec 2019',
    NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you identify those ID with `incorrect Flow`. You can do this by comparing `datediff(day, min(StartDate), max(EndDate))` and `sum(datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate))`

After that `JOIN` with `#Sample` to return the result. To display that extra line `Incorrect Flow` use `UNION ALL`

```
with err_id as
(
    select  ID, 
            DaysElapsed = datediff(day, min(StartDate), max(EndDate))
                        - sum(datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate))
    from    #Sample
    group by ID
    having  datediff(day, min(StartDate), max(EndDate))
    <>      sum(datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate))
)
select  s.*, DaysElapsed = datediff(day, StartDate, EndDate)
from    err_id e
        inner join #Sample s    on  e.ID    = s.ID

union all

select  ID, Status = 'Incorrect Flow', StartDate = NULL, EndDate = NULL, DaysElapsed 
from    err_id
```

Comment: Thanks @Squirrel, only problem is it doesn't show the DaysElapsed within your result set as what the difference is.

Comment: just added that